# C# - Stuck with use of list and array

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have been practicing c# nowadays and decided to write a code that converts any decimal to any base representation for practice purpose. And i have some troubles. Since i want to practice i decided to do it with an additional function where calculations take place. First i wanted to use an array to keep my result. But since ,at the beginning, i do not know the length of the array i could not define it.So i decided to use list(somehow i assumed undeclared slots are 0 as default). This is what i end up with.

```
class MainClass
{
    static double number;
    static double baseToConvert;
    static int counter = 0;
    static List<double> converted = new List<double>();

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a decimal");
        number = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a base you want to convert to");
        baseToConvert = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        ConverterToBase(number);

        for (int i = converted.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(converted[i]);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void ConverterToBase(double x)
    {
        double temp = x;
        while (x >= baseToConvert)
        {
            x /= baseToConvert;
            counter++;
        }

        converted[counter] = x;
        counter = 0;

        if (temp - x * Math.Pow(baseToConvert, Convert.ToDouble(counter)) >= baseToConvert)
        {
            ConverterToBase(temp - x * Math.Pow(baseToConvert, Convert.ToDouble(counter)));
        }
        else
        {
            converted[0] = temp - x * Math.Pow(baseToConvert, Convert.ToDouble(counter));
        }
    }
}
```

But after i write inputs console gets stuck without an error. My guess is that since i do not have any elements in the list " converted[counter] " does not make sense. But i do not know maybe the problem is somewhere else.

My question is not about the way i calculate the problem(Of course any suggestions are welcomed). I just want to know what i am doing wrong and how i can handle such situation(unknown array size , use of list , accessing a variable,array,.. etc  from another method... ).

Thanks.

Comment: Other bases, besides decimal, do not have decimals.  For example, how would you write 11.6 in hexadecimal?

Comment: by decimal i mean base 10 . forgive my english

Comment: Yes, I understood.  How do you expect to convert `11.6 (base 10)` to `base 16`?

Comment: You never add anything to your List. You can't just reference into it, you have to call the Add method.

Comment: @SamAxe  ~B.999 ..

Comment: Why would i convert 11.6 to base 16? The reason i declared them as double is because of math.pow accepts only doubles. And i did not consider the case of floating numbers.

Comment: Seems like this code has some logic issues and unnecessary code.

Comment: @DevinLiu it is not about being unnecessary code or not. it is about how to handle such situation.

Comment: Does OP need a collection in the code? The code only asks for input once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the method named "ConverterToBase(double x)" you want to set value of 0 element. But you didn't add any element. The converted is Empty. 
Firstly add value or values to your list.

Comment: Thank you.Finally a constructive answer. I tried adding "0"s before manipulating list and it seems like working. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

My previous answer was wrong as pointed out by @Rufus L. There is no infinite for loop. However upon further review, there seems to be an infinite recursion going on in your code in this line:

```
if (temp - x * Math.Pow(baseToConvert, Convert.ToDouble(counter)) >= baseToConvert)
    {
        ConverterToBase(temp - x * Math.Pow(baseToConvert, Convert.ToDouble(counter)));
    }
```

ConverterToBase calls itself and there seems to be no base case nor return statement to end the recursion.

Comment: What you say is true, but your 'numbers' aren't correct which might be confusing to him. `converted.Count` is 0 so `i` stars at -1, and thus never meets the termination condition which is **i is greater than or equal to 0**.

Comment: Both of you are correct. There's just a lot of issues with this code that I don't know where to start.

Comment: so i might need some help with this kind of situation.It seems list is not what i need but than how can i use an array wihout knowing size?

Comment: @FickyLicky Judging from your main function above, you don't need any collection to store input since you only ask for the inputs once. You can just store 'number' and 'baseToConvert' into two int variables. Then,  you should fix the logic behind the code.